# Fetch/Parse database data with accounts

Tags: php, ios, database, swift, macos

I want to create an iOS/OSX app that needs to fetch/parse data with a database considering each user account.

I'm new into databases and I would like to have something like : "if this is this x user, get the data of the x user".

I searched for tutorials on database management and it was talking about getting things like location, user infos but not with a secured access/account system.

How can I make it possible ?

Thanks for your future advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really dependent on what DB system you are using.  For example, if you are using Firebase, they can handle most of that for you.  If you are using your own mongoDB or mysql DB, you would either have to create your own user auth system or use an open source one that is compatible.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you !